# Showing progress encoding with libmp3lame

Tags: javascript, c++

I encode wave data with libmp3lame for javascript (the emscripten portage, so the methods are exactly the same as the c++ version).

It works, but the encoding can takes too long and I need to make a progress bar to show the progression. My problem is that I have no idea what functions of libmp3lame or events I can call or bind to make it real.

For the record (not sure it's very important to help me) here is my code:

```
mp3codec = Lame.init();
Lame.set_mode(mp3codec, config.mode || Lame.JOINT_STEREO);
Lame.set_num_channels(mp3codec, config.channels || 2);
Lame.set_out_samplerate(mp3codec, config.sampleRate || 44100);
Lame.set_bitrate(mp3codec, config.bitrate || 128);
Lame.init_params(mp3codec);

var mp3data;
for (var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
    mp3data = Lame.encode_buffer_ieee_float(mp3codec, inputBufferLeft[i], inputBufferRight[i]);
    addMp3Data(mp3data.data);
}

mp3Data = Lame.encode_flush(mp3codec);
addMp3Data(mp3data.data);

var final = new Blob([new Uint8Array(data)], { type: 'audio/mp3' });
```

Also if you have a link to the dev documentation, it would be awesome.

Thanks.